# How to stop selenium scraper from redirecting to another internal weblink of the scraped website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

Was wondering if anyone knows of a way for instructing a selenium script to avoid visiting/redirecting to an internal page that wasn't part of the code. Essentially, my code opens up this page:
https://cryptwerk.com/companies/?coins=1,6,11,2,3,8,17,7,13,4,25,29,24,32,9,38,15,30,43,42,41,12,40,44,20

keeps clicking on show more button until there's none (at end of page) - which by then - it should have collected the links of all the products listed on the page it scrolled through till the end, then visit each one respectively.

What happens instead, it successfully clicks on show more till the end of the page, but then it visits this weird promotion page of the same website instead of following each of the gathered links respectively and then scraping further data points located off each of those newly opened ones.

In a nutshell, would incredibly appreciate it if someone can explain how to avoid this automated redirection on its own! And this is the code in case someone can gratefully nudge me in the right direction :)

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException
import json
import selenium.common.exceptions as exception

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


webdriver = '/Users/karimnabil/projects/selenium_js/chromedriver-1'
driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
   


url = 'https://cryptwerk.com/companies/?coins=1,6,11,2,3,8,17,7,13,4,25,29,24,32,9,38,15,30,43,42,41,12,40,44,20'
driver.get(url)
links_list = []
coins_list = []

all_names = []
all_cryptos = []
all_links = []
all_twitter = []
all_locations = []
all_categories = []
all_categories2 = []

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='nav-item nav-guest']/a")
sign_in.click()
time.sleep(2)

user_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='login']")))
user_name.send_keys("karimnsaber95@gmail.com")

password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
password.send_keys("PleomaxCW@2")

signIn_Leave = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group text-center']/button")
signIn_Leave.click()
time.sleep(3)



    


while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-outline-primary']")
        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except exception.StaleElementReferenceException:
        print('stale element')
        break
print('no more elements to show')

try:
    company_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='companies-list items-infinity']/div[position() > 3]/div[@class='media-body']/div[@class='title']/a")
    for link in company_links:
        links_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
except:
    pass

try:
    with open("links_list.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(links_list, f)

    with open("links_list.json", "r") as f:
        links_list = json.load(f)
except:
    pass
    
try:
    for link in links_list:
        driver.get(link)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']/h1").text
        try:
            show_more_coins = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-original-title='Show more']")
            show_more_coins.click()
            time.sleep(1) 
        except:
            pass
        
        try:
            categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'categories-list')]/a")
            categories_list = []
            for category in categories:
                categories_list.append(category.text)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            top_page_categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='breadcrumb']/li/a")
            top_page_categories_list = []
            for category in top_page_categories:
                top_page_categories_list.append(category.text)
        except:
            pass


        coins_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'company-coins')]/a")
        all_coins = []
        for coin in coins_links:
            all_coins.append(coin.get_attribute('href'))
        try:
            location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='addresses mt-3']/div/div/div/div/a").text
        except:
            pass

        try:
            twitter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='links mt-2']/a[2]").get_attribute('href')
        except:
            pass
            
        try:
            print('-----------')
            print('Company name is: {}'.format(name))
            print('Potential Categories are: {}'.format(categories_list))
            print('Potential top page categories are: {}'.format(top_page_categories_list))
            print('Supporting Crypto is:{}'.format(all_coins))
            print('Registered location is: {}'.format(location))
            print('Company twitter profile is: {}'.format(twitter))
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            pass

        all_names.append(name)
        all_categories.append(categories_list)
        all_categories2.append(top_page_categories_list)
        all_cryptos.append(all_coins)
        all_twitter.append(twitter)
        all_locations.append(location)



except:
    pass



df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(all_names, all_categories, all_categories2, all_cryptos, all_twitter, all_locations)), columns=['Company name', 'Categories1', 'Categories2', 'Supporting Crypto', 'Twitter Handle', 'Registered Location'])

CryptoWerk_Data = df.to_csv('CryptoWerk4.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect calls happen for two reasons, in your case either by executing some javascript code when clicking the last time on the `load more` button or by receiving an HTTP 3xx code, which is the least likely in your case.
So you need to identify when this javascript code is executed and send an `ESC_KEY` before it loads and then executing the rest of your script.

You could also scrape the links and append them to your list before clicking the `load more` button and each time it is clicked, make an if statement the verify the link of the page you're in, if it is that of the promotion page then execute the rest of your code, else click load more.

```
  while page_is_same:
    scrape_elements_add_to_list()
    click_load_more()
    verify_current_page_link()
    if current_link_is_same != link_of_scraped_page:
      page_is_same = False
  # rest of the code here
```

Comment: You were on point. It turned out that the list of <a tags I was collecting - some of them contained some hrefs to this weird promotions tab - hence why the redirect happened. But your proposal actually helped me fix another issue that didn't speak of here. So this was really incredible, appreciate it, brother !